# How to poll live session SkyScanner API

Tags: skyscanner

I successfully create the Live Pricing Service Session and have the polling URL. I am trying to poll the URL with a GET according to [SkyScanner docs](http://business.skyscanner.net/portal/en-GB/Documentation/FlightsLivePricingList), but I keep getting the following `400 error`:

[image]

Comment: Are your inputs valid? Skyscanner throws ___"400 Bad Request"___ when the input validation has failed. Can you post your session url (**excluding the ApiKey**)?

Comment: you're right, the url parameters were not properly formed

Answer (score 0):

If you really successfully created the session poll URL. All you have to do is to add the apikey at the end of the session poll URL like this:

**Session Poll URL:** 
http://business.skyscanner.net/apiservices/pricing/hk1/v1.0//?apikey=